# Desplazar imágenes con hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo que realizar una carrera con hilos que tras presionar el botón de inicio se vayan desplazando las imágenes desde el inicio del `JFrame` hasta el final de una línea, después definir cuál de las imágenes fue quien llego primero y gano la carrera.

Nota: Las imágenes se deben mover por separados con una velocidad que sea random para que dichas imágenes se muevan a una velocidad distinta de la otra imagen.

Adjunto la imagen del `JFrame` para que se hagan una idea de cómo sería la carrera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo el código del `JFrame`.

```
package CarreraHilos; 

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class VentCarrera {


    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    ClsCarreraHilos carrera;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    VentCarrera window = new VentCarrera();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public VentCarrera() {
        initialize();   

    }


    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1027, 578);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); 

        JButton btnPausar = new JButton("PAUSAR");
        btnPausar.setBounds(292, 474, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPausar);  

        JLabel lblCasa = new JLabel("PALACIO DE NARI\u00D1O");
        lblCasa.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblCasa.setBounds(733, 13, 221, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCasa);

        JLabel lblObama = new JLabel("New label");
        lblObama.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/Obama.jpg")));
        lblObama.setBounds(26, 90, 90, 96);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblObama);

        JLabel lblPutin = new JLabel("New label");
        lblPutin.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/Putin.jpg")));
        lblPutin.setBounds(26, 228, 90, 67);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPutin);

        JLabel lblLineaPutin = new JLabel("_____________________________________________________________");
        lblLineaPutin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblLineaPutin.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        lblLineaPutin.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblLineaPutin.setBounds(26, 236, 793, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblLineaPutin);

        JLabel lblMaduro = new JLabel("New label");
        lblMaduro.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/Maduro.jpg")));
        lblMaduro.setBounds(26, 355, 90, 79);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblMaduro);

        JLabel lblLineaObama = new JLabel("_____________________________________________________________");
        lblLineaObama.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblLineaObama.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        lblLineaObama.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblLineaObama.setBounds(26, 113, 838, 45);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblLineaObama);

        JLabel lblLineaMaduro = new JLabel("_____________________________________________________________");
        lblLineaMaduro.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblLineaMaduro.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblLineaMaduro.setBounds(26, 355, 793, 43);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblLineaMaduro);

        JLabel lblBanderaColombia = new JLabel("New label");
        lblBanderaColombia.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/banderaColombia.png")));
        lblBanderaColombia.setBounds(853, 71, 130, 103);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblBanderaColombia);

        JLabel lblBC2 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblBC2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/banderaColombia.png")));
        lblBC2.setBounds(853, 197, 130, 103);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblBC2);

        JLabel lblBC3 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblBC3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/banderaColombia.png")));
        lblBC3.setBounds(853, 325, 130, 109);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblBC3);

        JButton btnIniciar = new JButton("INICIAR");
        btnIniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                ClsCarreraHilos carrera = new ClsCarreraHilos(lblObama, lblPutin, lblMaduro, 100);
                carrera.start();
            }
        });
        btnIniciar.setBounds(52, 474, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnIniciar);

        JButton btnDetener = new JButton("DETENER");
        btnDetener.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                carrera.stop();
            }
        });
        btnDetener.setBounds(529, 474, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDetener);

        JButton btnReiniciar = new JButton("REINICIAR");
        btnReiniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                carrera.stop();
                carrera.start();
            }
        });
        btnReiniciar.setBounds(785, 474, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnReiniciar);

        JLabel lblCasaNarino = new JLabel("____");
        lblCasaNarino.setIcon(new ImageIcon(VentCarrera.class.getResource("/Imagenes/casaNari\u00F1o.jpg")));
        lblCasaNarino.setBounds(-103, 0, 1132, 557);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCasaNarino);  

    } 
}
```

Y de esta manera tengo la clase con hilos.

```
package CarreraHilos;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ClsCarreraHilos extends Thread{

    JLabel lblObama;
    JLabel lblPutin;
    JLabel lblMaduro;

    int velocidad;

    // 730 es el rango máximo

    public ClsCarreraHilos(JLabel obama, JLabel putin, JLabel maduro, int velocidad) {
        this.lblObama = obama;
        this.lblPutin = putin;
        this.lblMaduro = maduro;
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
    }

    public void run() {

        /*
        int rangoMaximo = 100; 
        velocidad = (int) (Math.random() * rangoMaximo) + 50;
        */

        for (int i = 0; i <= 730; i++) {


            lblObama.setLocation(lblObama.getX()+1, lblObama.getY());
            lblPutin.setLocation(lblPutin.getX()+1, lblPutin.getY());
            lblMaduro.setLocation(lblMaduro.getX()+1, lblMaduro.getY());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000/velocidad);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

    }

    public void detener() {
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

Como puedo hacer que cada imagen sea independiente una de la otra, es decir que el movimiento sea separado y que me pueda decir quién ganó la carrera.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr que cada imagen se mueva por separado es sencillo.

```
int velMaduro = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);//Random 1-10
int velPutin = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);
int velObama = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10);
```

Se asignó a cada entero una velocidad random y a la hora de mover tus Jlabel cada uno tendrá su propia velocidad:

```
lblObama.setLocation(lblObama.getX() + velObama, lblObama.getY());
lblPutin.setLocation(lblPutin.getX() + velPutin, lblPutin.getY());
lblMaduro.setLocation(lblMaduro.getX() + velMaduro, lblMaduro.getY());
```

En cuanto a quien es el ganador, si el limite es 750 sobre el eje X, cada ciclo dentro del hilo hay que estar validando si alguna de los 3 JLabels ha sobrepasado dicha cantidad.

```
if (lblMaduro.getX() < 750 && lblObama.getX() < 750 && lblPutin.getX() < 750) {
}
```

Cumpliendo esa validación pasarías a una segunda en la que te asigne a un string el nombre de dicho competidor, algo sencillo y suponiendo que no hay dos randoms iguales sería:

```
if (lblMaduro.getX() >= 750) {
            ganador = "Maduro";
        } else if (lblObama.getX() >= 750) {
            ganador = "Obama";
        } else {
            ganador = "Putin";
        }
```

Mientras mas preciso quieres que sea mas validaciones tiene que tener.

Para reiniciar el evento, tienes que posicionar los JLabes en su estado original que si no me equivoco serían:

```
lblObama.setLocation(26, 90);
lblPutin.setLocation(26, 228);
lblMaduro.setLocation(26, 355);
```

Espero te ayude
Saludos

Edición:

Para la parte de que se paren existen dos formas, una es que se termine el ciclo de tu for u otra es cambiarle los valores que se asignaron a cada velocidad única todos a "0", así cuando le estas sumando ceros no se moverán, algo asi como:

```
public void pausa() {
    velMaduro = 0;
    velObama = 0;
    velPutin = 0;
}
```

este procedimiento puede funcionar tanto para finalizar como para terminar, lo que pasa es que tu usas un for, por lo que yo recomendaría que utilizaras un while con una bandera para que cuando quieras parar y checar quien gana solo cambies la bandera de estado por ejemplo:

```
boolean bandera = true;
    while (bandera) {
        //Aqui va todo tu contenido...
        if (elJLabel.getX() > 750) {
            bandera = false;
        }
        //Aquí validas quien gana...
    }
```

Lo otro que se ve en parches no entiendo a que te refieres, pero supongo que se ve como si no fuera fluido, eso lo arreglas haciendo mas corta la duración del Thread.sleep()

También te dejo las dos clases con las modificaciones que les hice para probar si estaba bien, lamentablemente no esta comentado, y no asigné todos los eventos como eran, pero espero te des a la idea de como se haría de forma diferente, te dejo el enlace aquí es de google drive en zip y solo trae las dos clases en .java [AQUI!](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16QLi10KeNZVunFzToEkoUQ4Nj5TsBtXp) Solo cambia las rutas de tus imagenes!!!

Saludos

Comment: Vale, me haz ayudado un montón pero ahora tengo dos problemas: El primero es que al llegar al límite, las imágenes siguen derecho es decir que no se detienen al final y por último no se mueven seguidas sino como por parches. ¿Qué podría hacer allí? Gracias.

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta y te pondré en la parte de abajo como puedes solucionarlo.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, ya funcionó, que hubiera hecho sin usted. (Y)